# What to do about the history tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we have a tag called [history](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)?  In one of its usages, it is synonymous with [historical-linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-linguistics).  In the other usage, it is about non-linguistic history – the history of a theory, social movement, convention, etc.  This latter category is where [What are the rationale of people speaking/teaching Esperanto?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/354/what-are-the-rationale-of-people-speaking-teaching-esperanto) and [What is the reasoning behind the selection of the IPA symbols?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/213/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-selection-of-the-ipa-symbols) fall.

What do people think we should do about this?

Comment: It will also overlap with etymology, I'm concerned by it too but maybe it can be used for all history stuff not covered by more specific tags.

Comment: We discuss the history tag also in the question ["Volunteers to write some tricky overlapping tag wikis"](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/94/volunteers-to-write-some-tricky-overlapping-tag-wikis/95#95)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, [history](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag should not be used for historical linguistics because there is already [historical-linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-linguistics) and because it's misleading (history refers to the study of past events in general), so it must be retagged.

As for the usage for non-linguistic history, I think just let users use it first, and later we decide whether it's useful or we should kill it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is much value in having a tag to encompass both these things, as they are pretty conceptually disjoint.  I would propose that we make a second tag, perhaps called [historical-context](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-context) for questions of the second type.  After time passes (and we are sure that there are no other uses for a history tag), we should make [history](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) a synonym of either [historical-linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-linguistics) or [historical-context](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-context).

Comment: It might also be worth giving some of these problem tags more time to crystallize. We're still a very new site and it's hard to guess how things will be used.